# Why do 120 or so geographical region names end in a and ia?

Tags: etymology, toponyms, geography, dialects, hebrew

The web contains lengthy lists one with about 120 names of major geographical regions that end in a and ia. Is there any merit to the idea that this might go back to the Hebrew words *raqa* and *raqia*? (If so it could help explain place names like Africa, Raqqa Syria, and Iraq.) The verb *raqa* involves making a plate (like gold plating, or even, crustal plating) and the noun *raqia* refers to the plate itself.

Comment: How would you get from Hebrew *raqa* / *raqia* to Latin / Greek *-a* and *-ia*? That seems like a difficult transition to show. For example, the best we know of Africa is that it comes from a Carthaginian or Phoenician word. I'm not sure about the origins of Syria beyond Ancient Greek. I'm also not sure how one would prove the suffix itself would come from a specific place name.

Comment: How many of those 120 names are of English origin (and not, say, Latin)? *Africa* and *Syria* are both Latin names (based on local words, but the *-ica* and *-ia* endings are Latin).  The point being, this doesn't appear to be a question about English.

Comment: Hey Juhasz, you are correct in that the list that has over 120 place names states that most are Latinized. But certainly not all. By the way, it's at (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KpXPc5QBGQVw3GVIUeAecE5WSBsgXfMhaua4xRfDztA/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Dunno if it's relevant that some place names *(**The Antarctic, The Argentine**)* take an ***-a*** suffix if and only if we discard the article *(**Antarctica, Argentina**)*.

Comment: Note also that the name "America" came from replacing "go" in the explorer name "Amerigo" with "ca". This does seem to suggest that the "a" suffix is associated with place names.

Comment: In Genesis, "rakia" is often translated as firmament, some kind of solid plane (though it says God called that layer Heaven). In Hebrew, the -a ending is simply feminine, and after all in English we also have one's homeland as motherland.